# How to call my own function inside an Angular Directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I'd like to call "myFunc()" inside my angular directive, how might I do this?

```
myApp.directive("test", function () {
 return {
   restrict: 'A',
     template: "<div class='box'></div>",
     myFunc: function() {
                console.log('myFunc');
       },
     link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

         element.bind('click', function () {
               myFunc(); //<------------- doesn't work
       });
     }
    } // of return
});
```

Comment: afaik it's not possible I think you should use scope : '&' and put the function in the controller but may be you just know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define the function as a property of your return value in your call to directive. It either needs to be defined before your return:

```
myApp.directive('test', function() {
    var myFunc = function() {
        console.log('myFunc');
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        template: '<div class="box"></div>',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', myFunc);
        }
    };
};
```

Or the same way inside of your `link` function.

Answer (score 0):

Just to play around :)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MainController',function() {

});
app.directive('one', function() {
    return angular.extend({}, app.directive, {myfunct:function(){
                alert('hello');
    }});
});
app.directive('two', function(oneDirective) {
    return {
        link:function($scope,$element){
            console.log(oneDirective[0].myfunct)
            $element.on('click',oneDirective[0].myfunct);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

or use the method binding "&":

```
app.directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            callback: "&"  
        },
        link:function($scope,$element){

             element.bind('click', function () {
               $scope.evalAsync(function() {
                  $scope.callback({param1: value, param2: value2});
               })
             });
        }
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
<my-dir callback="myControllerMethod(param1, param2)"></my-dir>
```